# About Isolated Page In My Web Site

Tags: seo, hyperlink

I Produced a page which I have no intention to let Search Engines find and claw it. 
The advisable solution is robot.txt. But it is not applicable in my  situation.

So I isolated this page from my site by clearing all links from other pages to this page, and never put its URL in external sites.

Logically, then, it is impossible for search engines to find out this page. And that means no matter how many out-bound links nesting in this page, the PR of site is save.
Am I right?

Thank you very much!

Hope this question is programming related!

Comment: How can robots.txt not be applicable?

Comment: Note: it's robots.txt , not robot.txt

Comment: Thanks, Piskvor. My mistake!

Richard OD!Thank you for your response. The Reason is complicated. One of them is that I need allow some obscure search engines craw to that page(I gave them the URL of the page), so as to indicates their links are exist in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's still a chance your page can be found by search engine crawlers.  For example, it's been speculated that data from the Google Toolbar can be used to alert Googlebot to the presence of a page.  And there's still a chance others might link to your page from external sites if the URL becomes known.

Your best bet is to add a [robots meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html) to your page, this will prevent it from being indexed, and prevent crawlers from following any links:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

Comment: Also, 'Safe Browsing' checks may reveal the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the internet and not restricted, it will be found.  It may make it harder to find, but it is still possible a crawler may happen across it.

What is the link so I can check? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have outbound links on this "isolated" page then your page will probably show up as a referrer in the logs of the linked-to page. Depending on how much the owners of the linked-to page track their stats, then they may find your page.

I've seen httpd log files turn up in Google searches. This in turn may lead others to find your page, including crawlers and other robots.

The easiest solution might be to password protect the page?

Comment: IE used to send the referrer header when you would type a new URL into the browser.  I think this is fixed now, but it used to give out many 'internal' URLs.

Comment: Password Protection seems enlightening to me, Thanks!